# win phone 7 change default dialer and play sound

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I'm wondering is it possible to write program for windows phone 7 like this:

I am talking with other person on the phone. I click the button in the aplication and it plays specific sound (e.g. from mp3 file) to the person i'm talking to, like I would play it directly to the microphone.

1. Is it possible to play sound to the person I am talking with?
2. Is it possible to change the dialer view (like you can change it in win mo 6 http://www.iconsoft.com/images/temporary/phonex/hdialer.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think either one is really possible.

When you launch the dialer you are using The `PhoneCallTask` launcher ([WP7 Launchers and Choosers](http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/07/windows-phone-7-launchers-and-choosers.aspx)), and you do not have access to the functionality directly.

If the user has the phone on speaker and you play the sound , it *may* be heard on the other end, but it wouldn't be great.

Sorry, I think you are out of luck on this one :(

For a list of the Launchers/Choosers see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: A "jailbroken" phone may provide this functionality, but I don't think that has even happened yet...

Comment: You still wouldn't because you don't have access to native code (I believe)

Comment: i have seen jailbroken iPhones change the look of the dialer. I would assume you could do the same on WP7